Poor predictions with phophet
I am trying to make forecasting in my dataset using prophet but my results are very poor.
I tried adding seasonality and and seasonality mode but the results on MAE and R-squared are very low.
Here's an overview of my dataset

and here's my code
# pandas
import pandas as pd
# prophet
from prophet import Prophet
# metrics
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_absolute_error

# holoviews
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts

# Create a new column to identify if the date is a weekday or weekend
df_prophet['day_type'] = df_prophet['ds'].apply(lambda x: 'Weekend' if x.weekday() >= 5 else 'Weekday')
df_prophet


threshold_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-10-01')
mask = df_prophet['ds'] < threshold_date
# Split the data and select `ds` and `y` columns.
df_train = df_prophet[mask][['ds', 'y']]
df_test = df_prophet[~ mask][['ds', 'y']]

def build_model():
    """Define forecasting model."""
    model = Prophet(
        yearly_seasonality=True,
        weekly_seasonality=True,
        # daily_seasonality=True,
        # holidays = holidays,
        interval_width=0.95,
        mcmc_samples = 1000,
        # seasonality_mode = 'multiplicative',
        seasonality_mode = 'additive',
        growth= 'linear'
    )

    # model.add_seasonality(
    #     name='daily',
    #     period=5,
    #     fourier_order=5
    # )

    return model

model = build_model()

model.fit(df_train)

# Extend dates and features.
horizon = df_test.shape[0]

future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=horizon, freq='D') # daily days predictions
# Generate predictions.
forecast = model.predict(df=future)

forecast.loc[:, 'yhat'] = forecast['yhat'].clip(lower=0)
forecast.loc[:, 'yhat_lower'] = forecast['yhat_lower'].clip(lower=0)

print('r2 train: {}'.format(r2_score(y_true=df_train['y'], y_pred=forecast_train['yhat'])))
print('r2 test: {}'.format(r2_score(y_true=df_test['y'], y_pred=forecast_test['yhat'])))
print('---'*10)
print('mae train: {}'.format(mean_absolute_error(y_true=df_train['y'], y_pred=forecast_train['yhat'])))
print('mae test: {}'.format(mean_absolute_error(y_true=df_test['y'], y_pred=forecast_test['yhat'])))

The results are quite poor though.

How can I improve my model?

Please don't use images of text, use the text instead. Also, what do you expect? In general, it would help if you provided a [mcve] which others can actually run in order to reproduce the behaviour.

@UlrichEckhardt Thank you for your comment. I couldn't figure how to add the dataset in order to make a MRE.
